# Sitemap with site owners using jquery/javascript

Tags: client-object-model

I am having scenario where i need to create site map webpart using jquery or javasscript i want to show all the subsites and their owners of each site with hieracrchy .can anyone help me in this.Thanks

Comment: That could be a lot of data to pull back.  Depending on the size of the site collection it could take quite some time to run.  Are you sure this is the right technology?  What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Hi Dave I am using sharepoint 2010...I am very new to this technology and was not sure how can i approach on this..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known [free solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82664/Site-Map-Web-Part-SharePoint-Server-2010) that does this but if you absolutely need to stick with Javascript/jQuery then you will probably need to get educated on the [Ecmascript Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372944%28v=office.14%29.aspx).  The full details of the object model are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253%28v=office.14%29.aspx).